# Не работает статический импорт в Java

Tags: java

Заинтересовала возможность статического импорта, однако eclipse и netbeans ругаются на такой код:

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
```

Поправил.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить Intellij Idea. Она вам и подскажет в чем проблема

Comment: Вот кстати на идее работает без нареканий, netbeans и eclipse мозги плавят.

Comment: Что говорит IDE, в общем-то побоку. Вы смотрите на ошибку, которую выдаёт _компилятор_.

Comment: В общем, дело было не в бобине. Я пропустил пакет в строке импорта и с внешнего пакета пытался обратиться к классу внутреннего. Вопрос можно закрыть. Всем спасибо.

Comment: Советую вам полностью переходить на Idea. Она круче Eclipsa, особенно для новичков

Comment: Не лезу в холивары, тем более что пользование идеей не бесплатно, а сообщество еклипса держится на энтузиастах, которые работают на качество, а не на выручку.

Comment: Идея бесплатна, если вам не нужна Java EE. Просто скачивайте Community Edition  с Java SE. Но если вы работаете над EE, то да, может быть в этом в этом случае Eclipse будет лучше)

Comment: + за Eclipse, для Java лучше редактора нет. Для Android, правда, пришлось перейти на Android Studio, так как поддержку ADT прекращают )=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse может ругаться на `import static java.lang.Math;` так как версия с билдером может не совпадать. Есть такой [баг](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7159016).

В случае Eclipse, такой вариант `import static java.lang.Math.*;` без ошибок выполняется. Для начала обновите Eclipse, если у вас совсем старая версия стоит.

Comment: Нет, пользуюсь всем самым свежим. Всё перепробовал - не хочет работать, даже ide другую попробовал.

Comment: @PirateNinja а Java то какая?

Comment: 8-ая, пробовал на 7-ой, ничего не поменялось.